# ¿Cómo se puede obtener la IP de una unidad de red?

Tags: c#, sql-server, redes

Para realizar una copia de seguridad desde un equipo local sobre una base de datos SQL Server que está en el servidor, necesito la IP de la unidad compartida S:/ obteniendola en C#.

El comando que ejecuto para las copias de seguridad es:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [<<NombreBBDD>>] TO  DISK = N'\\<<IP>>\<<NombreBBDD>>.bak'
```

Las etiquetas `"<< >>"` las uso para sustituir por las variables del C#, pero no tengo la IP.

He probado usando lo siguiente:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
var backup = builder.DataSource;
```

pero el `DataSource` me devuelve `IP\SQLEXPRESS` que no la puedo recortar ya que por otros motivos, la IP me varía.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el problema es obtener la ip de una unidad de red mapeada, puedes utilizar WMI para obtenerla:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
        "select * from Win32_MappedLogicalDisk");
string ip="";
foreach (ManagementObject drive in searcher.Get())
{
        if (drive["DeviceID"].ToString() == "S:")
        {
            ip = Regex.Match(drive["ProviderName"].ToString(),@"\\\\([^\\]+)")
                 .Groups[1].ToString(); 
        } 

}
```

Comment: No me permite usar el `ManagmentObjectSearcher` incluso si pongo delante `System.Management`, ¿sabes por que?

Comment: Tienes que agregar una referencia en tu proyecto a `System.Management`

Answer (score 0):

No se si lo he entendido bien, pero tal y como lo has resuelto es correcto. La propiedad DataSource te devuelve el servidor de la cadena de conexión que quieras. En el caso de que te devuelva `IP\SQLEXPRESS` tendrías que quedarte solo con la IP y listo.

En el caso de que varíe, como indicas, por desgracia te tocará resolver la IP cada vez que lances el backup.

Si es variable poco puedes hacer, salvo que puedas referenciar el servidor por algún nombre (DNS) asignado a esa máquina. Por Ejemplo: SERVIDORSQLSERVER. Si es una red local pregunta al administrador de vuestra red.

Comment: Allí esta el problema, la IP es variable y busco si hay alguna manera de no tener que tratar la IP cada vez.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes el *hostname* puedes usar el método ***GetHostAddresses*** (antes Resolve) de la clase ***DNS*** para obtener su IP correspondiente:

```
public static void DoGetHostAddresses(string hostname)
{
    IPAddress[] ips;

    ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostname);

    Console.WriteLine("GetHostAddresses({0}) returns:", hostname);

    foreach (IPAddress ip in ips)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    {0}", ip);
    }
}
```

Algo tarde la respuesta, pero espero que te sirva para este u otro proyecto.

Fuente: [DNS.GetHostAddress Method(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses(v=vs.110).aspx)

Agrego ejemplo con método [DNS.GetHostEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.dns.gethostentry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) que muestra sólo las direcciones IPv4:

```
        public static void doGetHostEntry(string hostname, bool soloIPv4 = false)
        {
            try
            {
                IPHostEntry ips = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname);
                Console.WriteLine("GetHostEntry({0}) returns:", hostname);

                IPAddress ipAddress;

                if (soloIPv4)
                {
                    foreach (IPAddress a in ips.AddressList)
                    {
                        if (a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("    {0}", a.ToString());
                        }
                    }                    
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var ip in ips.AddressList)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("    {0}", ip.Address.ToString());
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (SocketException ex )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ErrorCode + "- " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Ejemplo del su uso de ambas funciones:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string host = ".";
            while (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(host))) 
            {
                Console.Write("Nombre del host: ");
                host = Console.ReadLine();
                if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(host)))
                {
                    doGetHostAddresses(host);
                    doGetHostEntry(host, true);
                }
            }
        }
```

Resultado:

```
Nombre del host: es.stackoverflow.com
GetHostAddresses(es.stackoverflow.com) returns:
    151.101.1.69
    151.101.193.69
    151.101.129.69
    151.101.65.69
GetHostEntry(es.stackoverflow.com) returns:
    151.101.1.69

    151.101.193.69
    151.101.129.69
    151.101.65.69
Nombre del host:
```

Comment: Esta solución ya la habia contemplado y no me servia ya que accedo a una ruta compartida, mientras que el hostname me daba del equipo local.

Comment: Creo que hay una confusión, GetHostName te da el nombre del equipo GetHostAddresses te da la dirección IP

Comment: Pero dará la IP del equipo local, cuando necesitaba de otro equipo.

Comment: El único parámetro que pide es el nombre del hostname por ejemplo: DNS.GetHostAddress("www.mexico.gob.mx") te devolverá "69.172.201.104", y lo mismo para un host de tu red local; es equivalente a nslookup del sistema operativo, puedes tener dos inconvenientes: que te dé más de una dirección IP y que también incluye las direcciones IPv6, Agregaré datos adicionales a la respuesta, chécala.